# Add "tools" back to the close reasons?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

Can we please add tools to the list of off-site resources off-topic close reasons?

Currently its:

> It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

I propose (emphasis for diff):

> It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, **tools,** or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based **or spam** answers.

Added a note about potential spam answers too.

Comment: The new approach for post notices appears to be **as terse as possible,** and I am inclined to agree with it.  People generally don't read these things, but the shorter they are, the more likely they are to read them.  Gerrymandering the wording is a waste of time; the precise verbiage doesn't really matter all that much.  You don't need the word "tools" in the close reason to use it anyway; it's covered under "other off-site resources."

Comment: Seemed reasonable to me at first read, but then I have to agree with Robert. My tendency is to be complete and descriptive, even at the risk of verbosity. But people tend not to read it, and it really doesn’t do any good anyway. One possibility is to change “software libraries” to just “software”, which would cover libraries, APIs, *and* tools. Less is more, perhaps, in this case.

Comment: I think "other off-site resources" nicely encompasses "tools". Making an exhaustive list will probably not benefit enough people to matter - most reasonable people will get the meaning. If we add "tools", should we then add "articles" (it's not a book)? Or "frameworks" (it's not a library)? Or "applications" (it's not a tool)? When do we stop and assume that people will *get it*? To me, the current wording is where it's at - it's basically "don't ask for written things or automated things to do your job or anything similar to these".

Comment: The new post notices don't say anything other than "off topic" for questions closed for this close-reason ([example question closed as a resource request](//stackoverflow.com/q/44377119/3773011)). The only places this description is displayed is in the close-vote/-flag dialogs. It's also available from the SE API (which is how I verified the above question was closed as a resource request). I posted [a bug report about this](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/337914/271271), which was marked as [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. So, overall, I don't see that changing this would have much impact either way.